# R: convert decimal point to comma in xtable string (for LaTeX)

Tags: r, xtable, decimal-point

I'm using xtable to convert an R table into an object, which can then be printed as a LaTeX table. In this table, I need single numbers to be printed in different colors. Therefore, I already substituted these numbers **before** applying the xtable function using

```
paste0("\\textcolor{black!25!green}{",x.tab[[4]][i],"}",sep="")
```

where x.tab is my R table.

The .tex file looks fine and is compiling without any error. Still, I need these colored numbers, that are captured in a string now, with a **decimal comma**. All non-colored numbers are in the right format, because I use

```
format.args = list(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
```

in my print function.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using `options(OutDec = ",")` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prettyNum` function to set your format :

```
x <- c(1.6, 2.8, 1.3)
y <- c(0.067, 8.1, 7.55)
d <- data.frame(x, y) 
print(xtable(prettyNum(d,decimal.mark=",")))
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I already tried that but didn't succeed, probably because I have other pre-defined formatting arguments when calling my print function.